# jquery cant use after/insertafter after nth-of-type

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue using after/insertafter after the nth type of element. I am trying to conditionally add a new section. If I use the selector with something like .html() it works as expected, but just can't add something after. I also tried using wrap and selecting the nth of type of that, but same deal. Here's the selectors. Does this not work or something?

```
    $('.wrap div:nth-of-type(2)').after('<div id="test">yo</div>');
    $('<p> hello </p>').insertAfter('.mgrid_table table:nth-of-type(2)');
```

Code:

```js
$('.mgrid_table table:nth-of-type(2)').after('<p>hello</p>');
$('.mgrid_table').eq(1).after('<p>yo</p>');
$('<p> hola</p>').insertAfter('.mgrid_table table:nth-of-type(2)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test <td>info 1</td></tr>
</table>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test2<td>info 1</td></tr>
</table>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test3<td>info 1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and the result you're trying to create with this?

Comment: Functions like `after()` and `insertAfter()` don't care what selector you used. They just operate on the collection that's returned by the selector.

Comment: I did it with eq() instead of nth of type, not really sure why this didn't work though..

Comment: Post an MCVE if you want help instead of guessing.

Comment: Ok I put one together for the hell of it, just to see the difference. Table structure is basically the same and still doesn't work with nth of type https://jsfiddle.net/4ezm2pbt/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `.mgrid_table table:nth-of-type(2)` is wrong. That searches for the 2nd `table` inside an element with class `mgrid_table`. But the table isn't inside that class, it *is* the element with that class. The correct selector is `table.mgrid_table:nth-of-type(2)`.

Remember, a selector of the form `x<space>y` means to look for `y` inside `x`.

```js
$('table.mgrid_table:nth-of-type(2)').after('<p>hello</p>');
$('.mgrid_table').eq(1).after('<p>yo</p>');
$('<p> hola</p>').insertAfter('table.mgrid_table:nth-of-type(2)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test <td>info 1</td></tr>
</table>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test2<td>info 2</td></tr>
</table>
<table class= "mgrid_table">
<tr>test3<td>info 3</td></tr>
</table>
```